# Print RDLC reports with duplicate and triplicate copies

Tags: c#, rdlc, reportviewer, microsoft-reporting

I am using C# with Visual Studio 2015.
I have a rdlc report ready to be printed in ReportViewer. How can I print same report multiple times? I need to print invoices with duplicate copies. Single copy of rdlc is already available but how to print second copy of same report?

Comment: Do you mean you're using the ReportViewer control? In my experience the print icon found within the control displays the standard printing form allowing you to choose a printer, preview, change number of copies, etc.

Comment: Yes using reportviewer, but I would like to print multiple invoice copies with different heading like "Original Copy" for first page, "Duplicate copy" for second page and "Transport Copy" for third page if any. So reportviewer page print is not an option

Answer (score 3):

Are you using [PrintDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) to print the first copy? If so there is a setting for the number of copies.

```
var pd = new PrintDocument();

// Specify the printer settings to use.
pd.PrinterSettings.Copies = 3;
```

Comment: I am printing invoice within reportviewer only.

Comment: @Hemal: You should consider the solution above anyway, just add "print" button on the form and hide default print button in report viewer, this way you can decide how many copies you need to print.

Comment: @InitK I would like to print multiple invoice copies with different heading like "Original Copy" for first page, "Duplicate copy" for second page and "Transport Copy" for third page if any. So reportviewer page print is not an option

Comment: @Hemal This is exactly what I'm trying to suggest. If you must show "preview" for user, then do it in a shape of Report viewer, but hide default "print" button of report viewer and place your own button on the form (if it's windows app) or on the page (if it's web app) and place all the printing logic behind that button. You cannot get away with simply using  PrinterSettings.Copies properties in your case, but you can create print output with as many different versions of the report as you like "behind the scenes".